# Шифрованние данных Android в Firebase

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-database

Вопрос по шифрованнию данных в Firebase.
В общем. Если делать авторизацию пользователя через Гугл, то это все идет через https, если я все правильно понимаю. И там шифрует сам сервис Firebase.
А что, если делать авторизацию через логин+пароль, но данные будут в Базе Данных. Что делать в этом случае ? Подскажите, мб есть еще какие-то варианты, почитаю. Спасибо.

Comment: https - это не о данных в базе. Это про шифрование трафика между устройством и сервером - оно осуществляется не зависимо от способа авторизации.

Comment: А если работать с БД Firebase, то весь трафик идет через https, поэтому, шифрованние есть, верно я понимаю ?